# How do I access the checkbox in listview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, date, listview, checkbox

I'm trying to access the ID as FindControl but it doesn't return the value, giving me the object not instantiated error.
How can I access its ID?
I've tried several things and so far I don't know how to solve this problem.
PS: I'm new to C# programming

### ASP.NET

```
<ItemTemplate >
                                            <tr id="item" runat="server" class="row">
                                                <td class="first">
                                                    <asp:Label ID="lblNumero_titulo" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("numero_titulo") %>' /><br />
                                                </td>
                                                <td><%# Eval("razao_social") %></td>
                                                <td><%# Eval("hora_entrega")%></td>
                                                <td><%# Eval("quem_recebeu")%></td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="testecb" runat="server" /> </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <asp:Label ID="lblCodEntrega"Visible="false" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("cod_entrega") %>' /><br />
                                                </td>                                                  
                                            </tr>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
```

### C#

```
protected void btnPesquisar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        limpaCampos();
        using (PrincipalDataContext pdc = new PrincipalDataContext())
        {

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtCodRomaneio.Text))
            {
                var romaneios = pdc.z_stp_anb_transp_receb(Convert.ToInt32(txtCodRomaneio.Text)).ToList();
                var r = romaneios.First();
                var check = lvNotas.FindControl("testecb") as CheckBox;

                if (romaneios != null)
                {

                    if (r.status == 1)
                    {
                       check.Checked = true;
                       check.Enabled = false;

                    }

                    lvNotas.DataSource = romaneios;
                    lvNotas.DataBind();
                }
                else
                {
                    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page), UniqueID, "alert('Romaneio não encontrado!')", true);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: if `lvNotas` is a list box then you can not locate the checkbox directly under it. The checkbox is inside an item of the listView. So you first need to locate the item of ListView and then use `FindControl` on that item.

Comment: where is the makup for your button? I don't see it. If the button is outside of the lv, then what row is the button supposed to operate on? You would have to select a lv row - and pick which row of the lv to operate on. You could drop/move the button into the lv row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
The way you get/grab the check box is a list view is like this:
```

Markup:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID" >
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr style="">
                <td><asp:Label ID="First" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FirstName") %>' /></td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="Last" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("LastName") %>' />
                </td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="Hotel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("HotelName") %>' /></td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="CityLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("City") %>' /></td>

                <td align="center">
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
                </td>

            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <table id="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" border="0" class="table table-hover">
                <tr runat="server" style="">
                    <th runat="server">FirstName</th>
                    <th runat="server">LastName</th>
                    <th runat="server">HotelName</th>
                    <th runat="server">City</th>
                    <th runat="server">Select</th>
                </tr>
                <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
                </tr>
            </table>
        </LayoutTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CssClass="btn-info" Height="38px" Text="Show checked" Width="130px" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
        <br />
```

so we now see this:

[image]

So we can check a few check boxes as per above.

Now, the button code to see/view/get/grab/work with the selected rows?

This:

```
   protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        {
            foreach (ListViewDataItem lvRow in ListView1.Items)
            {
                CheckBox chBox = (CheckBox)lvRow.FindControl("CheckBox1");

                Debug.Print("Row = " + lvRow.DataItemIndex + ", " + "PK id = " 
                    + ListView1.DataKeys[lvRow.DataItemIndex]["ID"] + ", " 
                    + "Checked = " + chBox.Checked);
            }
        }

    }
```

Output:

```
Row = 0, PK id = 73, Checked = True
Row = 1, PK id = 72, Checked = True
Row = 2, PK id = 153, Checked = True
Row = 3, PK id = 95, Checked = False
Row = 4, PK id = 144, Checked = False
Row = 5, PK id = 102, Checked = False
Row = 6, PK id = 82, Checked = False
Row = 7, PK id = 76, Checked = False
Row = 8, PK id = 107, Checked = False
Row = 9, PK id = 108, Checked = False
```

NOTE VERY carefully how we DID NOT include the database PK value in the display nor in the markup (datakeys collection is used). This is nice, since then we don't have to display, nor even include the database PK value (ID) in the list view, but we are free to get/grab that PK value.

So the above shows how to process (get) the checked rows. We could of course move the button to the list view row, and have one button click operate on the one given row - but your question did not show the button click in the mark up, so I don't think you want one button click to get one row - but you can do this (if you place/have a button on each row of the list view).

And the code to load the lv is this:

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
        LoadGrid();
        }
    }

    void LoadGrid()
    {

        using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 10 * from tblHotels ORDER BY HotelName ",
            new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4)))
        {
            cmdSQL.Connection.Open();
            ListView1.DataSource = cmdSQL.ExecuteReader();
            ListView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
```